# Why do the edges of my mesh invert?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am new to blender and I am trying to follow a tutorial on how to make a donut. When I added the icing and tried to extrude the edges, they did this weird inversion thing, shown in the picture. [image]

How do I fix this issue and make the drops "inflate" again? Also, how did this happen in the first place so I can avoid it in the future?

Comment: What tutorial are you following, or, even better, how did you create the frosting? What edges are you extruding?

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing more of how you got to this point, but some things to try are to: 1) select the whole mesh in edit mode, press M (merge), and select "by distance", then 2) with the mesh still selected, pick `Mesh > Normals  > Recalculate Outside` from the menu at the top. However, I know Andrew uses a solidify modifier on the icing, which flips the normals, if I remember, so you might need to recalculate inside instead.